# Centering an image in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to fix my grid layout.

Firstly, the image should be at the center of `.container`. I tried using `align-self: center;`, but that did not work.

The headers and paragraph are really messed up. Before this, the paragraph was pushing down the image so I thought if I gave both of them (and the headers) custom `grid-row` value, they'd be fixed, but instead, I have all of these elements overlap each other. I need them to be ordered correctly. The paragraph under H3 and H3 below H1.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

.container img {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.container h1,
h3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  line-height: 0.35;
}

.container p {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>-[IFwsI]- Jail</h1>
  <h3>More than 40 000 registered players</h3>
  <p>The most active, and one of the most successful servers. Jail has a set of rules players need to follow and enjoy the roleplay of inmates vs. CTs scenario</p>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/epqMIJv.jpg" height="418" width="740" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create columns for the text and image to make it easier to manage the columns.

Take a look at `grid-template-columns` you can control the widths of each column in myriad ways. I have just set them to `33%` width;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

`justify-content: center` puts the columns in the horizontal center.

`align-items: center` aligns the items vertically.

To change the order I've created a new class `.column--left` with `grid-row: 1` to put move it to the first column.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column.column--left {
  grid-row: 1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <h1>-[IFwsI]- Jail</h1>
    <h3>More than 40 000 registered players</h3>
    <p>The most active, and one of the most successful servers. Jail has a set of rules players need to follow and enjoy the roleplay of inmates vs. CTs scenario</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column column--left">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/epqMIJv.jpg" height="418" width="740" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No... you see... I need that image to be on the left and the paragraphs on the right. That is why it became so complicated to make the layout.

Comment: More like that?

Comment: @Sarcoma you can add `height: 100vh;` to `.container` to see an effect on `align-items: center`

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Could you also explain what did you add and why? I still cannot seem to resolve my problem with this.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Did you get it sussed out?

Comment: Yes, I understood it and also resolved the issue with the help of your code.

Answer (score 0):

> *...but instead, I have all of these elements overlap each other.*

In your code, you are specifically telling them to overlap each other.

```
.container h1, h3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  line-height: 0.35;
}

.container p {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 350px;
}
```

The `h1`, `h3` and `p` are all placed in column 3, row 1. Why wouldn't they overlap?

Here's another approach that may be useful to you:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: " . pic header1 . "
                       " . pic header3 . "
                       " . pic  ptext  . "
                       " . pic  ptext  . "                       
}

.container > h1  { grid-area: header1; }

.container > h3  { grid-area: header3; }

.container > p   { grid-area: ptext;   }

.container > div { grid-area: pic;     }

.container img   { width: 100%; object-fit: contain;  }

*                { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>-[IFwsI]- Jail</h1>
  <h3>More than 40 000 registered players</h3>
  <p>The most active, and one of the most successful servers. Jail has a set of rules players need to follow and enjoy the roleplay of inmates vs. CTs scenario</p>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/epqMIJv.jpg" height="418" width="740" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s1hu8f6m/19/)

Here's a visualization of the code using [Firefox's grid overlay tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts).

[image]

Comment: The headers and the paragraph should be straight below one another, there should not be that space that your code has. Can that be fixed too?